# Как подключить барометр BMP280 к Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

У меня имеется барометр BMP280 (HW-611).

[image: барометр BMP280]

Я его подключал разными способами. Я использовал библиотеку Adafruit для BMP280, запустил пример bmp280test, но пишет "check wiring". Как его подключать, какую брать библиотеку?

Comment: Вот тут смотрели? https://arduinomaster.ru/datchiki-arduino/datchiki-atmosfernogo-davleniya-bmp280-bmp180-bme280/

Comment: У меня датчик похожий, тоже называется BMP280, работает вот с [этой](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6zvN79LeKYkYnQwZXZ6V1M1ZE0) библиотекой.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего используется неправильный адрес устройства. Поставьте адрес 0x76.

```
  if (!bmp.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!"));
    while (1);
  }
```